# String length with shell script

Tags: shell-script

I am working with GRASS and I have a problem with a one-dimensional vector of numbers. Now, I want to print the length of that vector because my output is looks like this:

```
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,)
```

when it should look like this:

```
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

i.e., I don't need the last separator. Is there a way to do that?

I want POSIX-compliant solutions; no bashisms.

My code looks like this:

```
for i in $CATS
do 
 step=$step"$i,"
 echo $step
 g.region --overwrite vector="region_uspo_$i," save=regions_uspo
 regions_uspos="region_$i,"
 echo $regions_uspos
done
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to state clearly what you are asking. Do you need help evaluating the length of a string? Do you need help with subtracting 1 from another number? Do you want to fix your `$step` variable after the loop so it doesn’t have the extra comma? Do you want to fix your `$step` variable *at every iteration of the loop* so it doesn’t have the extra comma?  What do you want / need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the last comma after you've finished building the string.

```
for …
done
step=${step%,}
regions_uspos=${regions_uspos%,}
```

`${VARIABLE%PATTERM}` expands to the value of `VARIABLE` with the shortest suffix matching `PATTERN}` removed. This construct is supported in every POSIX shell. It's supported in all BusyBox configurations as well.

If you need the intermediate strings without a trailing comma, you can strip off the trailing comma inside the loop. Alternatively, build the strings without a trailing comma by adding a comma before the appended element. To avoid having an initial comma, detect the first iteration through the loop.

```
first=1
for … do
  if [ -n "$first" ]; then
    first=
  else
    step="$step,"
    regions_uspos="$regions_uspos,"
  fi
  step="$step$i"
  …
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this. One way is to create a new variable, e.g. sep, which is initially empty and is set to a comma just after you say `step="$step$sep$i"`.

Another way is to use conditional expansion, so you say

```
step="${step+${step},}$i"
```

Where the ${name+value} expands to value if name is set. In this case the value is "$step," assuming I am typing this correctly on the phone.

Another way is to just remove the first comma from the variable after you have accumulated the values into it.

Comment: Even though I feel this is the closest to what I had in mind my output using (step="${step+${step},}$i") is this : `regions_1,2,3,4,5,5` and what I need is : `regions_1,regions_2,regions_3,regions_4,regions_5`.

Comment: If your input is 1 2 3 4 5 and you need the output to be reg1,reg2,reg3,reg4,reg5 then use `step="${step+${step},}reg$i"`

Comment: Yeah, I realized what I've said and created an solution. look above

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so apparently the answer was the following:

```
for i in $var
do 
 step=$step"region_$i,"
done

step=${step%,}
echo $step
regions_uspos=${regions_uspos%,}
```

and it was based of @Gilles answer